# How to fix TypeError: 'int' object is not callable from a divided number

Tags: python, integer, callable

Im trying to create a program to generate text with usernames from a txt file but I keep getting a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` i know what this means but I have no idea how to fix my issue. I tried just doing `y = 12 / 2` and the same error came up when i passed the for loop `y` i am really confused so if someone could help me that would be great

This is my code

```
def generateNum():
        #imports random
        from random import randint

        for _ in range(10):
            value = randint(0, 900000)
            return(str(value))

def getNumOfLines( file):
        #opens txt file
        with open(file) as f:
            Lines = f.readlines()
            count = 0
            # Strips the newline character
            for line in Lines:
                count += 1

            return(count)
class debug:
    def __init__(self, credsTxt, tagsTxt):
        self.credsTxt = credsTxt
        self.tagsTxt = tagsTxt

        self.numOfCreds = getNumOfLines(credsTxt)
        self.numOfTags = getNumOfLines(tagsTxt) 

        self.ammountPerAccount = round(self.numOfTags / self.numOfCreds)   

    
    def getComments(self):
        #initializes comment
        comment = ""
        #opens txt file

        file1 = open(self.tagsTxt, 'r')

        count = 0
        while True:
            count += 1
        
            # Get next line from file
            line = file1.readline()

            for i in self.ammountPerAccount:
                # if line is empty
                # end of file is reached
                if not line:
                    break
                comment += ' ' + line.strip() + ' ' + generateNum() + '.'  
            return(comment)
                


print(debug('D:/FiverrWork/user/instagram-bot/textGen/assets/login_Info.txt', 'D:/FiverrWork/user/instagram-bot/textGen/assets/tags.txt').getComments())
```

this is my stack trace error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\FiverrWork\user\textgenerator\textgenerator\txt.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(debug('D:/FiverrWork/user/textgenerator/textgenerator/assets/login_Info.txt', 'D:/FiverrWork/user/textgenerator/textgenerator/assets/tags.txt').getComments())
  File "d:\FiverrWork\user\textgenerator\textgenerator\txt.py", line 47, in getComments
    for i in self.ammountPerAccount():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your code does not match the traceback. It looks like the code is corrected and the traceback is the result of a different version of your script being run.

Comment: It looks like the offending line is: `for i in self.ammountPerAccount:`. I see from above that you assign: `self.ammountPerAccount = round(...`, so I take it to be an `int`. What do you actually want the `for` loop to do since you cannot iterate over an `int`?

Comment: @KlausD. no this is correct i just ran it and it does the same

Comment: @quamrana so i want it to run that code x amount of times x being the value of  ammountPerAccount

Comment: Oh, so you meant to write: `for _ in range(self.ammountPerAccount):`

Comment: @quamrana i just tried it thanks it worked if u post the answer ill give u credit for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop as posted cannot iterate over an `int`. You meant to iterate over a `range()`:

```py
for _ in range(self.ammountPerAccount):

    # if line is empty
    # end of file is reached
    if not line:
        break
    comment += ' ' + line.strip() + ' ' + generateNum() + '.'
```

I used `_` as a placeholder variable since the actual value of `i` each time was not used.